# Run co-occurrence algorithm in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I found the following project on github https://github.com/fbukevin/hadoop-cooccurrence which uses a co-occurrence algorithm in hadoop.

I’m using a virtualized Ubuntu 14.04 and managed to install hadoop as a single node cluster with this instruction http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php. I'm new to hadoop and this are my first attempts to run a program with yarn.

I can execute the command `yarn` in command line, but I don’t know how to run the co-occurrence algorithm in `yarn`. In the description it says that the program can be used with the following command

`$ yarn jar <hadoop>.jar [pairs | stripes] <input_file>`

So I tried this:

```
$ yarn jar /home/vmiller/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar pairs pg100.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pairs
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

This is definitely not correct but I don't know how to run the command correctly. Somehow I have to tell `yarn` to use the `Cooccurrence.java` located in `hadoop-cooccurrence/src/main/java/cooc/Cooccurrence.java` because this file seems to be the one that executes the co-occurrence algorithm. But how do I tell yarn to use this file with the `pairs` and `stripes`arguments on the input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to run the programm. My approach wasn't that wrong, as tokiloutok mentioned I had to include the right jar file.

Before I could execute the command I had to import the `pg100.txt` into HDFS.

So I had to deactivate the safe mode of the name node with

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

and import the file with

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/vmiller/workspace/hadoop-cooccurrence/pg100.txt /user/hadoop/
```

so that I could finally run

```
yarn jar target/cooc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar pairs pg100.txt
```

without getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should give jar the path to the jar including the Cooccurrence class.
Jar is in target folder (cooc-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar).

You don't need to indicate the class name as it is set up in the Manifest file